# jquery IF not working as expected on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have functions with same name and each is expected to trigger on varied pages.
It works fine on android and pc but not on iphone.

```js
if($('main').is('.a')){
  function submit(){
    alert('a');
  }
}
if($('main').is('.b')){
  function submit(){
    alert('b');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="a">
  <a href="#" onclick="submit()">anchor</a>
</main>
```

On iphone it alerts 'b'!!!

Comment: why you have two function with same name? you could have written if condition inside function

Comment: and if you want to check for class than you can use `hasclass()` too in if

Comment: It will return b in most cases, since the last defined value of an element (in this case the function) will always be the one used. Although it's dependable on the scope of your function. Better practice is to use different names for your function OR put it all in a single function.

Comment: you should use an ELSE.  The issue is the timing if events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should write single function and write `if` condition inside it. Use `hasClass` to identify if element has particular class

```js
function submit(){
  if($('main').hasClass('a')){
    alert('a');
  } else if($('main').hasClass('b')){
    alert('b');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="a">
  <a href="#" onclick="submit()">anchor</a>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think all code you just need to wrap with in a function.

```
<main class="a">
  <a href="#" onclick="submit()">anchor</a>
</main>
<script>

function submit(){
 var tag=$('main');
 if(tag.hasClass('a'))
  { 
    alert('a');
  }
  if(tag.hasClass('b'))
  { 
    alert('b');
  }
 }
</script>
```